# How to send data to another page?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sapper

I have a function `getData()` which is launch on `submit` when my input text is not empty,

Index.svelte

```
<script>
    let inputValue = '';

    let responseData;
    async function getData(){
        let url = new URL('url');
        url.search = new URLSearchParams({
            url: inputValue
        })

        const response = await fetch(url);
        const repositoryData = await response.json();

        responseData = repositoryData;
        goto()
    };

  </script>
```

How to send data returned from this function to another page (`Home.svelte`) to show this data on simply dashboard?

thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean by saying *"send data to another page"*?

Comment: i mean that, i get from api data on `Index.svelte` but I show this data on `Home.svelte`

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store).

`_stores.js`

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

// have a store
export const searchResult = writable(null)
```

`Index.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import { searchResult } from './_stores.js';

    let inputValue = '';

    let responseData;
    async function getData(){
        let url = new URL('url');
        url.search = new URLSearchParams({
            url: inputValue
        })

        const response = await fetch(url);
        const repositoryData = await response.json();

        // equivalent to: searchResult.set(repositoryData)
        $searchResult = repositoryData; // <================== set the store

        goto()
    };
</script>
```

`Home.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import { searchResult } from './_stores.js'
</script>

<!-- read the store -->
{#if $searchResult}
  {#each $seartResult as $result}
    ...
  {/each}
{:else}
  <p>Enter your search</p>
{/if}
```

You might consider moving your fetch logic to stores too, by making `searchQuery` a writable store, and `searchResult` a derived store that makes the API call each time `searchQuery` changes.